# Getting User Information using SimpleMembership

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, viewdata, user-data, simplemembership

Still trying to get to grips to the new SimpleMembership with MVC4.  I changed the model to include Forename and Surname which works fine.

I want to change the information displayed when logged in so instead of using User.Identity.Name in the View I want to do something like User.Identity.Forename, what's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5):

Yon can leverage `@Html.RenderAction()` feature available in ASP.NET MVC to display this kind of info.

**_Layout.cshtml View**

```
@{Html.RenderAction("UserInfo", "Account");}
```

**View Model**

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public bool IsAuthenticated {get;set;}
    public string ForeName {get;set;}
}
```

**Account Controller**

```
public PartialViewResult UserInfo()
{
   var model = new UserInfo();

   model.IsAutenticated = httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

   if(model.IsAuthenticated)
   {
       // Hit the database and retrieve the Forename
       model.ForeName = Database.Users.Single(u => u.UserName == httpContext.User.Identity.UserName).ForeName;

       //Return populated ViewModel
       return this.PartialView(model);
   }

   //return the model with IsAuthenticated only
   return this.PartialView(model);
}
```

**UserInfo View**

```
@model UserInfo

@if(Model.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <text>Hello, <strong>@Model.ForeName</strong>!
    [ @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account") ]
    </text>
}
else
{
    @:[ @Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account") ]
}
```

This does a few things and brings in some options:

1. Keeps your view from having to sniff around the HttpContext. Let's the controller deal with that.
2. You can now combine this with an [[OutputCache]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) attribute so you don't have to  render it in every single page.
3. If you need to add more stuff to the UserInfo screen, it is as simple as updating the ViewModel and populating the data. No magic, no ViewBag, etc.