# How to check if the current visitor is already logged in?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, simplemembership

I want to implement an alert box to alert the current visitor to log in or register to continue browsing in my ASP.net MVC 4 web application. Can someone explain how to check if the current visitor is already a member or logged in?

Some background about my web app:

1. Visitors can visit my website to track which events are available (for participation);
2. Visitors need to register first (on my website) before they can participate at the events.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting User Information using SimpleMembership](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572819/getting-user-information-using-simplemembership)

Comment: It depends on your login authentication. Please, share your user login action. Which way do you use for users register/login?

Comment: Which ways are there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

It returns `true` if the user is logged in, and `false` otherwise.